# Какой алгоритм LL или Packart парсера?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Хочу разобраться в алгоритме нисходящего синтаксического анализатора. Но исходники либо слишком сложны и запутаны. Либо в книгах по построению лексических, синтаксических анализатором или компиляторов информация в виде математических формул. Хотелось бы в виде блок схемы простой и понятной, или на Python. Может подскажете где можно такое найти.

Comment: книгу дракона уже читали?

Comment: Да, дома лежит.

Comment: она должна не лежать, ее нужно читать и читать. До полного просвещения. А ещё можно поискать "Креншоу - давайте напишем компилятор". Если и там никак  - тогда уже сложно.

Comment: сначала стоит определиться с грамматикой, которую хочешь анализировать. Чем проще грамматика, тем проще и синтаксический анализатор получится.